# ListViewItem size larger than 256px

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, virtual, tile

Добрый день.
Как известно размер *ImageList* не может быть больше 256 пикселей.
И именно от размера *ImageList* зависит размер ListViewItem.

Но при использовании *View.Tile* можно задать какой угодно размер *TileSize* и затем уже отрисовывать картинки и текст.
Метод тоже конечно не идеальный, но был бы вполне приемлемым, если бы *Tile* можно было бы использовать в режиме *VirtualMode*.

Есть ли еще какие-то решения для отображения *ListViewItem* размером более 256 пикселей?
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как оказалось ограничение ImageList в 256 пикселей искуственное
и вполне можно создать HImageList, вероятно любого размера, используя WinApi.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/bb761522(v=vs.85).aspx
Соответственно размер ListViewItem устанавливается в размер нашего HImageList.

```
const int LVM_SETIMAGELIST = LVM_FIRST + 3;

var handle = ImageList_Create(value.Width, value.Height, ILC_COLOR4, 0, 0);
// применяем к ListView
if (handle != IntPtr.Zero)
    SendMessage(owner.Handle, LVM_SETIMAGELIST, (IntPtr)ImageListType.Large, handle);

[DllImport("comctl32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern IntPtr ImageList_Create(int cx, int cy, uint flags, int cInitial, int cGrow);

[DllImport("comctl32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern IntPtr ImageList_Destroy(IntPtr HIMAGELIST);

public enum ImageListType
{
    Large,
    Small,
    State
}
```